# Angular Type assertion doesn't happen for FormGroup when used as Input

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-formbuilder

I have multiple forms in different components. I am using formBuilder to create my formGroups for typed forms. When I am passing the created formGroups to a child component through @Input, I don't see the type assertion passed. Is there a way to do this to know the type of a formControl.

Parent Component:

```js
public form1 = this.formBuilder.group({
 name: ["", Vaidators.required]
 enabled: [false, aidators.required]
});

public form2= this.formBuilder.group({
 date: ["", Vaidators.required]
});

public form3 = this.formBuilder.group({
 data: ["", Vaidators.required],
 recurring: [true, Vaidators.required]
});

public form = this.formBuilder.group({
  form1: this.form1,
  form2: this.form2,
  form3: this.form3,
});
```

```html
<child1 [form1]="form1"></child1>
<child2 [form2]="form2"></child2>
<child3 [form3]="form3"></child3>
```

Child Component:

```js
@Input()
form1: FormGroup;
```

```html
<form [formGroup]="from1">
 <input type="text" formControlName="name" />
</form>
```

**I know that I can create a Interface for each formGroup and use it in the child components. But, I would like to know if there is another way to do this.**

```js
interface form1 {
 name: FormControl<string>;
}

form: FormGroup<form1> = new FormGroup({
 name: new FormControl("")
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there is no other way to enforce type assertion in Angular, other than creating interfaces for each `FormGroup`. This means that declaring your input to be of type just `FormGroup` makes it default to being of type `FormGroup<any>` - that is the reason why your IDE/compiler cannot infer the type of the form you pass.